# Update 1st row always of sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, updatelistitems

I am using REST API to update in custom list of SharePoint Server. It is a dashboard and displays result as per logged in user. Is it possible to update 1st row always using REST API irrespective of ID of row? Rest API is updating table but I want to update 1st row always.

**CODE:**

```
function UpdatePendingListItem(value)  
{  

    $.ajax  
    ({  
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<LIST_NAME>')/items(<ITEM_ID>)", // list item ID  
        type: "POST",  
        data: JSON.stringify  
        ({  
            __metadata:  
            {  
                type: "SP.Data.<LIST_NAME>ListItem"  
            },  
           COLUMN_NAME1:value,
COLUMN_NAME2: loginName 
        }),  
        headers:  
        {  
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
            "IF-MATCH": "*",  
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"  
        },  
       async: false,  
        success: function(data, status, xhr)  
        {  

        },  
        error: function(xhr, status, error)  
        {  

        }  
    });

}

**code to call function and update:**
getListItemsForView(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'<list_name>','<View_name>')
.done(function(data)
{
     var items = data.d.results;
    console.log("Waiting For Approval=" +data.d.results.length);
     //for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
       //  console.log(items[i].Title);
     //}    

 if(DashboardItemCount==0)
{
      CreatePendingListItem(data.d.results.length);
}
else
{
UpdatePendingListItem(data.d.results.length);
}
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by 1st row? 1st item in list or you have created custom table where you have bind the SharePoint list items and you want to update the 1st row of table?

Comment: I want to update 1st row always i.e items in 1st row.It is the only row which is existing in a table.

Comment: This is custom table, right? You have fetched list items using REST API and those to custom table??

Comment: yes,this is a custom table/list.I have fetched items from another list using rest api and added/updated into this custom table/list.

Comment: Are you using button click to update item or what?

Comment: I am not using button click.On load of page,update operation is perormed.On load,rest api is called

Comment: Can you add the code, how you have bind data to custom table? that will be easy to answer your question.

Comment: I have added update function code which is called for update

Comment: Update function code is generic. I am asking about the code you used to bind the fetched SharePoint list to custom table so that I will get the better idea how you have bind those items to table and how you can get the ID of first row of your column.

Comment: added the code..

Comment: Then you can use `data.d.results[0].Id` as ID of 1st item(from the results you are getting from your REST call).

Comment: @GaneshSanap your solution is working fine for me.But it is not working properly if I login with another user.As it is a dashboard,it should differ per user.It is differing in same way but while updating using data.d.results[0].Id,it is conidering 1st lists's id i.e. to othe user's list id.So it is not updating on cuurently login user's id.How can I find that what is current user's list id?

Comment: I am not getting you, what do you mean by current user's list id? Is your dashboard showing data different data to every user(based on permissions or any other field in list)?

Comment: Yes,it shows different data to every user.But no worries.I  added rowId=$(".ms-listviewtable>tbody>tr").attr("id"); and passing row id to update and it is working

Comment: Great. That is what I was saying in 2nd step in my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
var rowId=$(".ms-listviewtable>tbody>tr").attr("id")
```

in success of rest api call and passing rowid as id of a row,solved my issue.

As I display different list per user,I have to use this approach.

I f your list is same for every user then you can go for `data.d.results[0].Id` approach also.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow steps like below:

1. Fetch the list items from SharePoint list.
2. Bind the list items to your custom table along with the ID of list item (If you don't want to show the ID to user then you can hide that column from table using CSS).
3. Whenever you are calling update item function, you can pass the ID of first row of your table instead of `<ITEM_ID>`.

   `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<LIST_NAME>')/items(<ITEM_ID>)"`

Comment: Actually I am confused with this approach.List's ID column is auto incrementing.According to your approach,if I pass ID of first row the it's the same

Comment: Can you please add the code, how you have bind data to custom table?